# EF Core Updating Entity Property with JSON Type

Tags: entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have a 1 to many relationship of **Parent** and **Child** to store some data. I want to store this data in PostgreSQL using **Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL** package. **Parent** maps to a table, but Child is stored as a **json** column of **Parent** table in the database.

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "json")]
    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to add a Child entity to an existing Parent instance with the code below, SaveChangesAsync doesn't produce an update command on the database.

```
var child = new Child(){Id = 0, Name = "Name"};
var parent = await DataContext.Parent.SingleOrDefaultAsync(f => f.Id == 1);
parent.Children.Add(child);

await DataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

In order to trigger an update command, I have to set parent entity's **State** to **Modified** before calling **SaveChangesAsync**.

```
var entry = DataContext.Entry<Parent>(parent);
entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Is this the expected behavior or am I missing something?

**Update:**
As @SvyatoslavDanyliv suggested, instead of using **ICollection** when I use a class **EqualityCollection** derived from **List** and override **Object.Equals** as follows :

```
    public class EqualityCollection<T> : List<T>
    {
        public override bool Equals(object? obj)
        {
            if (obj != null && obj.GetType() == typeof(EqualityCollection<T>))
                return this.Equals(obj as EqualityCollection<T>);
            return false;
        }

        public bool Equals(EqualityCollection<T> obj)
        {
            return this.SequenceEqual(obj ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return base.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Change detection doesn't detect the change in the property and update command is not triggered.

Comment: Which class is hidden under `ICollection`?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv  What do you mean by hidden? **ICollection<Child> Children** holds a collection of child objects under Parent.

Comment: List, Array, HashSet? Anyway as I saw from EF Core sources for correct changes detection type should support `IStructuralEquatable` or you hould override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. So try to create your collection based on `List`, for example, and override Equals.

Comment: As @SvyatoslavDanyliv suggested, I used a class derived from List and override Equals, however it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Check that your Equals is. called. Put breakpoint on it.

Comment: Even  I add item to collection before SaveChangesAsync is called, Equals method is called but parameter (obj) is the same as object (this) and it returns true.

Comment: I understand. Let me check EF Core sources, maybe there is way to inject custom ValueComparer for snapshot.

Comment: Well, i have found documnetation. It’s easy ValueComparer is needed when defining conversion https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-comparers?tabs=ef5

Comment: Yes, as you stated setting a new **ValueComparer** on **OnModelCreating** worked. I used `c => c.ToArray().ToList()` as snapshot expression that might be not pretty though. If that valuecomparer could be set as annotation on the domain model, It would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `ValueComparer` when defining conversion via `HasConversion` as described in documentation: [Value Comparers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-comparers?tabs=ef5)